# Cloud service for webrole running in ARM Resource group

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

My understanding so far on PaaS deployment using WebRoles or Worker Roles-

- Spinning Web roles or Worker roles will create Cloud service to manage it.
- However, in ARM resource group, their is no concept of Cloud service, then how are web & worker roles managed in ARM resource group?
- Also I tried adding the webroles via JSON Outline in VS 2015, but no option to add webroles. So not sure if you can deploy webroles via JSON template?

Any information will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Resource Manager Web apps rely on the concept of App Service Plans, rather than cloud services. Basically this is the underlying VM(s) that the service runs on. You can specify the size and number of servers that make up the App Service plan, and then deploy on to those as a single unit.

You create an App service plan, then run web / worker roles inside that (as well as Logic, API, Functions)

As far as Web / Worker roles are concerned, App Service Plans do not draw a distinction between the two. You simply deploy code to it and it will run it however it is packaged. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2015/03/31/applying-a-web-and-worker-roles-pattern-to-the-azure-app-service/)

The concept of cloud services simply don't exist within the Azure Resource Management model.

You can find a template for deploying a Web App  [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-github-deploy/azuredeploy.json)

Comment: as per Microsoft article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

"An App Service plan represents a set of features and capacity that you can share across multiple apps, which include Web Apps, Mobile Apps, Logic Apps, or API Apps, in Azure App Service."

So not sure if it still supports Web roles or Worker Roles?

Comment: This answer is actually addressing Web Apps, not Cloud Services. Web and worker roles have nothing to do with Web Apps (or App Service Plans).

Comment: both answers in this thread are wrong\misleading. While there is no official support for Cloud Services in the ARM api, it is perfectly possible to deploy them using ARM Api.@Jason

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Services have been around since the beginning of Azure.
To the deploy or manage them, you have to use the old APIs ([Azure Service Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460799.aspx)).
As far as I know, they won't be migrated to the new APIs (Azure Resource Manager), but you could use [Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview/) instead.

Comment: But then - 

How are web & worker roles managed in ARM resource group?

Comment: You can't manage those with ARM. But there are newer services, which are ARM based and provide a similar  functionality, e.g. VM Scale-Sets, App Services, etc.

Comment: This makes no sense, vmss doesn't replace Cloud Services, nothing replaces those, which is a pity. @SaschaDittmann

Comment: @4c74356b41 I do not see why scale set was recommened in place of cloud services -- I do not see any correlation, we can't deploy cloud service packages to scalesets :-(